# Mouse Lag in UNO Wpf/Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, uwp-xaml, uno-platform

Im trying to build a high performance app on UNO platform (WPF/Windows/Wasm) that allows the user to draw primitive shapes (lines, rectanges, etc) Since it will have snapping to points, and showing snap point it should be smooth.

The mouse lags when moving over the canvas, the lag is small, but users of this app will be working very quickly and these lags make it feel unresponsive. Is there any way to speed this up?

A simple white box demo

MainPage.Xaml

```
   <Grid>
        <Canvas  Width="2088" Height="2100.17014099374" x:Name="MainCanvas" >
            <Canvas.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#eaeaea"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Ellipse Name="SnapPoint" Canvas.Top="400" Canvas.Left="400" Width="25" Height="25" Fill="Blue"></Ellipse>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

MainPage.Xaml.cs

```
 private void MainCanvas_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(MainCanvas).Position;

     Canvas.SetLeft(SnapPoint, position.X);
     Canvas.SetTop(SnapPoint, position.Y);
  }
```

I have also tried binding the Left and Top properties of the ellipse to view model, but the delay is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was using remote desktop from Mac to Windows, this caused a delay in the mouse pointer on the screen